# How to automate testing of Chrome packaged apps?

Tags: google-chrome-app

For regular web sites there are various tools to perform automated UI testing of applications, e.g. [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). However, how do I do this for Chrome Packaged Apps? My applications heavily uses Chrome App-specific APIs, so hosting it as a regular web page for testing won't work.

Any best practices or tools for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the app window handle, then Selenium Webdriver will still work. I discovered this by accident when I had a call to `driver.getAllWindowHandles()` at the end of a bunch of failed tests. The tests failed because they didn't have the reference to the app window handle, but -- unexpectedly -- the last call to returned two window handles instead of one.

It may seem like the app window handle never appears after calling `driver.getAllWindowHandles()`, but if you keep calling this function, eventually its callback will receive an array of window handles containing both the browser [0] and app [1] window handles. I've gotten this to work via recursion but not with a simple while loop (something something webdriver being asynchronous).

For example, if you dig the javascript implementation of webdriver, try running the following test from this relevant [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=271969).

```
describe('A chrome app html page', function() {
  var appHandle = "";
  var recursionDepth= 0, maxDepth = 100; // edit as necessary.
  function getAppWindow(){
    browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles){   
      if(handles.length == 1){
        recursionDepth += 1;
        if (recursionDepth == maxDepth) return false;
        getAppWindow();
      }
      if(handles.length == 2){
        browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
        browser.driver.getWindowHandle().then(function(currentHandle){
          console.log("handles are" + handles);
          console.log("current handle is " + currentHandle);
          appHandle = currentHandle;
        });
      }
    });
  }
  getAppWindow();
  it('is on the second window handle', function(){
    expect(browser.driver.getWindowHandle()).toEqual(appHandle);
  }, 20000);
});
```

You will need the --load-and-launch-app= flag set somewhere, as Antony has helpfully pointed out. My protractor config file looks like this:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: '<address of server>',
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions':{
      'args': ['load-and-launch-app=<path to app code directory>']
    }
  },
  specs: ['<path to tests>']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some ways I think testing chrome apps is similar to testing native applications - typical approaches used there include building extra hooks into your code for tests, and making use of OS-supplied automation tools (accessibility services, OSX automator, etc.)

Here's one thing that may help: chrome supports a command-line flag:

```
<path to chrome> --load-and-launch-app=<path to app code directory>
```

which, on startup, will cause it to load an unpacked version of your app's source code (equivalent to hitting "load unpacked extension.." from the chrome://extensions page) and then send the chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched event to your code.