# Automating chrome packaged apps?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome-app, kiosk

Is it possible to automate Chrome packaged apps? Since it opens a new app window (upon open) selenium was not able to identify it.

Tried searching it in Internet, but did not find proper answer to it.

Similar question but answer is not convincing **([How to automate testing of Chrome packaged apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21022837/how-to-automate-testing-of-chrome-packaged-apps))**

Comment: Hi, did you tried to handle opening window?